# Graphql-Ruby Mapping using Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql-ruby

I am completely new to using Rails, I'm trying to create a basic crud application using ruby-graphql to do a simple find query with active record to a sqlite3 database.
I set up a user type

```
  class UserType < Types::BaseObject
    description "A user type "
    field :id, ID, null: false
    field :username, String, null: false
    field :email, String, null: false
    field :email_confirmed, Boolean, null:false
    field :first_name, String , null:false
    field :last_name, String, null:false
    field :biography, String, null:true
    field :avatar, String, null:true
    field :created_at, GraphQL::Types::ISO8601DateTime, null:false
    field :updated_at, GraphQL::Types::ISO8601DateTime, null:false
  end
```

Then I setup the query :

```
field :user, UserType, null:false,
      description: "Get a single user" do
      argument :username, String, required: true
      end
    def user(username:)
      User.find(username)
    end
```

My query is :

```
{
  user(username:"test"){
    username
  }
}
```

I  get the following error :

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "no implicit conversion of #<Class:0x000000000b975440> into Hash",
    "backtrace": [
      "C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/graphql-1.9.13/lib/graphql/schema/field.rb:519:in `block in resolve'",
```

If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.
How do I do this conversion in Ruby / Rails?

Comment: You have another problem here in that `.find` is used to find records by id. If you want to find records by another unique column use `.find_by(username: username)`. Thats also a somewhat strange use of keyword arguments.

Comment: Thank you max, I don't actually know proper usage I'm just trying to hack away and learn while doing what would be a better way?

Comment: Well if you only have one argument then it makes more sense that its a positonal argument. And I would name the method something that tells you about what it actually does like `find_user_by_username`.

Comment: Is this the same when you use graphql-ruby https://graphql-ruby.org/fields/arguments , I'm just trying to follow the docs here. It still displays the same error even with find_by

Comment: I've tried to use find and the id as well and I still get this same problem. If anyone has any clues or they think they know whats going on I would really appreciate any advice or suggestions.

Comment: ```field :users, [UserType], null:false, description: "Get all the users"


    def users
      User.all
    end```
This code when I query for all users raises no issues.

Comment: In schema.rb it tries to call 
``` if extended_args.any?
                  field_receiver.public_send(@resolver_method, **extended_args)
                else
                  field_receiver.public_send(@resolver_method)
                end
```
 It tries to call the public send passing in the extended_args of query:1 and throws an error. If any ruby / graphql-ruby experienced developers could help, I'd be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was an issue with Ruby gem I was using upgraded to the new gem and it solved the problem. See - https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/issues/2537